# How do I get "Active" Courses from Desire2Learn Valence API?

Tags: desire2learn

Is there any way to check if a course is Active.

I currently retrieve a list of courses for an instructor by:

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/(/D2LVERSION: //version/)/enrollments/users/(/D2LID: //userId/)/orgUnits/
```

Once I have the list of enrollments for the user, I can filter which 
ones the user is an Instructor in.

Once I have the courses the user is an Instructor in, how can I check 
which ones are active?

I see that the data MyOrgUnitInfo may be available in the call:

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/(/D2LVERSION: //version/)/enrollments/myenrollments/
```

However, this is not applicable to me, as I am getting enrollments based 
on a userId

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to use the "myenrollments" call to retrieve the enrollments within the instructor's calling user context, then the route to find out which courses within an identified user's enrollments are active is a bit more complex.

1) You can first use

```
/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/user/{userId}/orgUnits&roleId={roleId}&orgUnitTypeId={orgUnitType}
```

to filter the list of returned enrollments by role and by org unit type: use the "instructor" role ID and the org unit type ID for course offerings in the call.

This will fetch you back a paged list of `OrgUnitInfo` structures, which in turn contain the org unit ID for all the org units.

2) Once you have this list of org unit IDs, you can test each one in the list to see if its active with

```
/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/courses/{orgUnitId}
```

This will fetch back the `CourseOffering` structure for each course, containing an `IsActive` property telling you if the course offering is active or not.

Comment: When executing the call as specified I get: '430 Forbidden' error. What  permissions are required for this call?

Comment: There is a permission called "See Course info" that needs to be set.

Comment: Also calling account needs "View User Enrollments" and to have the "Search for '<rolename>'" permission for the role the target is enrolled in the course as. If the "Search for '<rolename>'" style permission is not set it will not cause 403 errors but instead reduce which enrollments are returned from the query.